# jQuery .clone changes onchange to onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

When i clone a object using jQuery, if it's a select the 'onchange' event changes to 'onclick'. How do i clone an element with jQuery keeping all the attributes and events? Already used .clone(true).

Here is the code for JS:

```
function addNovoPasseio (obj){
    newobj=$(".passeios").clone(true);
    $(newobj).find("*").removeAttr('id');
    $(newobj).insertBefore("#addPasseio");
}
```

And here is the HTML code that i'm trying to clone:

```
<div class="passeios">
    <div class="select-cidade">
         <label for="cidade">Cidade</label>
         <select name="cidade" id="cidade" onchange="getBairros(this,$(this).parent().next().find('select'));" class="select-obr">
             <option value="-1">&nbsp;</option>
             <option>Cidades</option>
         </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="botoeira" id="addPasseio"><button onclick="addNovoPasseio(this);">New</button></div>
```

Comment: What leads you to believe the event gets changed?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for more than just a regular clone but something more like a deep copy.

Download the deepCopy.js from: http://oranlooney.com/deep-copy-javascript/

Then you can create an exact copy with the following:

```
var myCopiedItem = owl.deepCopy(myItem)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try to clone like this:

```
.clone(true, true)
```

You can always check events bound to an element:

```
$('selector').data('events')
```

Comment: `.data('events')` was removed in 1.8, you should have never used it anyway since it's internal.

Comment: Also $('selector').data('events') does not register events added inline.

Comment: According to the documentation, `.clone(true)` is the same as `.clone(true, true)`. *"By default its value matches the first argument's value"*.

Comment: The strange thing is that the onchange changes into onclick for some reason i don't know.

Comment: Done it, the problem was all about the orientation of the object i was trying to change.